# How to sort files by file extensions through the command line?

Tags: command-line, sort, file-extension

This is my question: How to sort files by file extensions through the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
ls -Xl
```

From the man file:

```
 -X                         sort alphabetically by entry extension
```

This is an example of how you could move .txt files into a test forlder:

```
mv *.txt test/
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. Yet, it is not exactly what I wanted. I guess my question isn't that clear now that I read it again. What I would want is to move files from one folder into a specific folder by using the file extension. Turns out I managed by using the mv command.

Comment: I've added a mv command to move files based on extension. Cheers